# Filtro para os próximos 90 dias linq ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, filtro

preciso fazer um filtro com linq em uma entidade, esse filtro deve trazer todos os eventos para os próximos 90 dias.

Exemplo de hoje: 11/01/2017 até 11/04/2017 (90 dias)

```
_con.SiteContexto.AsNoTracking()
.Where(e => e.Data....).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
DateTime filtro = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90);

var r = db.SiteContexto.Where(x => x.DataEnvio < filtro && x.DataEnvio > DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

Pega todos os registros quem tem a data maior que agora e menor que (agora + 90 dias)

**ATUALIZANDO:**

Melhorando um pouco a explicação:

O DateTime.Now vai retornar a data e hora atual. Para montar com o último minuto do dia e não o primeiro você pode fazer isso:

```
DateTime filtro = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(90)
                              .AddHours(23)
                              .AddMinutes(59)
                              .AddSeconds(59)
                              .AddMilliseconds(999);
```

Com isso o `< filtro` vai recuperar todos os do último dia também.

Você pode variar com isso, como adicionar 91 dias (`.AddDays(91)`) em vez de adicionar como sugerido mais acima.

Obrigado pelo comentário jbueno.

Comment: Cuidado com as horas!

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, melhorei um pouco a resposta!

Comment: **`DateTime.Now`** vai retornar a hora atual e não com "zero horas".

Answer (score 3):

> Obter todos os eventos com data igual ou maior a hoje **e** menor ou igual à (hoje + 90 dias).

É importante usar a função `TrucateTime()` para desconsiderar as horas.

```
_con.SiteContexto
    .Where(e => DbFunctions.TrucateTime(e.Data) >= DbFunctions.TrucateTime(DateTime.Now) &&
                DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.Data) <= DbFunctions.TrucateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(90))
    .ToList();
```

Se estiver usando uma versão do Entity Framework anterior à 6, use [**`EntityFunctions`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) ao invés de [**`DbFunctions`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx)