# Entity framework 6.2.0 + Find

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6

Olá, estou utilizando um método de busca com entity framework e oracle, e encontrei um problema com datas.

Na minha busca utilizo a seguinte lógica:

```
Find(x => x.Data_Intencao >= Periodo.Date, c => c.SubOrigem_EF);
```

Porém na minha `Data_Intencao` ela está fazendo a busca com a data e a hora.
Se eu coloco `Data_Intencao.Date` é apresentado o seguinte erro:

> *'The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'*

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14857/erro-ao-passar-adddays-em-express%C3%A3o-lambda/14862#14862 Leia

Comment: outro link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176823/filtro-para-os-pr%C3%B3ximos-90-dias-linq-asp-net-mvc/176832#176832

Comment: no seu caso em especifico: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/176832/54880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o método `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(data)` para utilizar a data e ignorar o horário.

```
Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Data_Intencao) >= Periodo.Date && c => c.SubOrigem_EF);
```

Comment: Fiz desta forma: var teste = Find(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Data_Intencao) >= Data_Inicio.Value.Date, c => c.SubOrigem_EF); e obtive o mesmo erro

Comment: Esse campo `Data_Inicio` é do banco de dados? Na pergunta não possui esse campo, nela possui o `Periodo`.

Comment: é uma variável, uma data qualquer!

Comment: Tente alterando para `Where`

Comment: DbFunctions.TruncateTime(data)! Assim funciona, deu errado da primeira vez porque não utilizei esse método na variável PERIODO. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplesmente zerar a hora da data de corte do Periodo.Date ou criar uma função estendida:

```
 DateTime date = new DateTime(Periodo.Date.Year, Periodo.Date.Month, Periodo.Date.Day, 0,0,0);

Find(x => x.Data_Intencao >= date, c => c.SubOrigem_EF);
```

Ou para deixar mais elegante:

```
    public class Periodo
{

    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }

    public Periodo(DateTime date)
    {
        Date = date;
    }
}

public static class DateTimeCustom
{

    public static DateTime ToZeroHora(this DateTime source)
    {
        return source.AddHours(-source.Hour).AddMinutes(-source.Minute).AddSeconds(-source.Second);

    }
}

Find(x => x.Data_Intencao >= Periodo.Date.ToZeroHora(), c => c.SubOrigem_EF);
```

Comment: O problema, é que essa hora já vem zerada. O problema é que eu quero filtrar apenas com os dias 01 e o dia final do mês independente da hora

Comment: O código que você colocou no exemplo expressa o filtro de uma data igual ou maior, não consegui entender o que você quer fazer. Poderia passar um exemplo do que viria na Data_Intencao e o que viria no Periodo.Date e qual resultado espera?